# find all the double cosets $AxA$ of $A$ in $G.$

Tags: abstract-algebra

If G is $S_3$ and $A = ( ( 1 2))$ in $G,$ find all the double cosets $AxA$ of
$A$ in $G.$

i know  that If $G$ is a finite group, then  the number of elements in the
 double coset $AxB$ is $$\dfrac{o(A)o(B)}{o(A\cap xBx^{-1})}$$

Here  im confusing that  how can i  find all the double cosets $AxA$ of
$A$ in $G.$ ?

Comment: any one     help  me,,,,???

Comment: Since $G$ is quite small, you can do it by hand. Note that $AxA=\{x, gx, xg, gxg\}$, where $g=(1,2)$. So $AxA$ has either two or four elements, depending if $gx=xg$ or not, respectively.